Onboarding Process
Hi I have got into big 4 company cleared technical round hr round after that got the confirmation from the company that I was selected. But haven't recieved any link for documentation what shall I do. Shall I mail my HR to ask about the update or wait for them?

Yes, if several days passed already and you did not receive any feedback about the next steps, send an e-mail and ask.
